# How to return from read function in Non-Canonical mode and VMIN and TIME not equal to ZERO

Tags: c, linux, unix, terminal, system-calls

I am working in a project in which I need to read data from the USB port of my Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) computer.

I am using read function to read data from the terminal in Non-canonical mode and VTIME = 5 (0.5 sec) and VMIN = 255, which means that it will block until the first char arrives and then the timer will start as stated here:

> In case of both TIME and MIN are nonzero. In this case, TIME specifies
>   how long to wait after each input character to see if more input
>   arrives. After the first character received, read keeps waiting until
>   either MIN bytes have arrived in all, or TIME elapses with no further
>   input. read always blocks until the first character arrives.

What I want to do is to force the return from the read function if it doesn't receive any character for more that five seconds.

What should I do ?!

Answer (score 0):

As I read here : http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanonical-Input.html

```
VTIME = 50
```

will do.

Comment: What written in the link you have referred to is if MIN is 50 and you ask to read just 10 bytes? Normally, read waits until there are 50 bytes in the buffer (or, more generally, the wait condition described above is satisfied), and then reads 10 of them, leaving the other 40 buffered in the operating system for a subsequent call to read. It's about VMIN and not VTIME

Comment: So you want to not block if no characters come at all?

Comment: Loop the function without VMIN. If read did't read anything exit the loop.